# Set option to show the slider in post - WP

Tags: theme-options

In the WordPress admin/dashboard under "Add New Post", I want to set an option for if someone wants to show posts in a slider: Yes/No.

[image]

And upon the option I need to do something like this in the post page:

```
if ( isset( $post_slider ) ) {
    // show slider code goes here
}
```

Comment: start here: [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

Comment: By default i want the option for all my post , I dont want to create a custom variable for each new post i create.

Comment: http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/1881/2wos.jpg some thing as shown

Comment: [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and search the [metabox tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metabox) here, many examples.

Comment: Thanks chap., i didnt knw they wer called as metabox . :P let me try and ping you back :)